# Load an image using MTKTextureLoader without flipping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, metal, mtktextureloader

It seems like `MTKTexureLoader newTextureWithContentsOfURL...` automatically flips the image. This causes all of my models and meshes containing conventional UV coordinates to display incorrectly. I didn't see anything in the options to specify whether this happens or not. Is there some way to use [`MTKTextureLoader`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MetalKit/Reference/MTKTextureLoader_ClassReference/index.html) and maintain the orientation of the image?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anyway to get `MTKTextureLoader` to flip your image, but you can simply flip your texture coordinates:

```
{ u, v } -> { u, 1-v }
```

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 10, you can pass an [option](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metalkit/mtktextureloader/1682242-texture_origin_options) to the `MTKTextureLoader` initializer. For example loading a texture from a CGImage:

```
let textureOut = try textureLoader.newTexture(with: cgImage, 
    options: [MTKTextureLoaderOptionOrigin: MTKTextureLoaderOriginTopLeft as NSObject])
```

will flip images that initially have their origin in the bottom left corner.

If you have to deal with iOS < 9, you can <s>force your users to update</s> use both approaches from Rythmic Fistman or Denn Nevera in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose MTK PreLoader creates a right texture from image according to the MTL Coordinate system: [...The origin of the window coordinates is in the upper-left corner...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html).

I think you have three simple options to process your image with normal orientation:

1. prepare already flipped image
2. flip your image in MSL graphic or kernel function in your app (as it has been offered in the first answer before, [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix))
3. in case when you need to present the image on an app view only, use view.layer.transfrom property, for instance: ...transfrom=CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI),1.0,0.0,0.0